# Convert .py to .exe that works on all windows?

Tags: python, py2exe

I converted my gui.py to gui.exe with py2exe, but it works only on windows 8 64 bit, when I tried it on win7 32 bit , it won't work

this code that converted .py to .exe

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['gui.py'])
```

any way to convert .py to .exe that works on all windows operating systems  ...?

Comment: Dont u wonder why there are two different pakages of python versions for 64 bit and 32 bit windows?

Answer (score 2):

You're building a 64-bit .exe, which won't work on 32-bit Windows. Install a 32-bit copy of Python and use that to make the package - it will be 32-bit then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called pyinstaller.  Install it using `pip install PyInstaller`.  To use it follow these steps.

1. In command line do `pyinstaller your_file.py`
2. In file explorer go to your your folder where the python file was created.  In that folder you will see a folder called dist.  In that folder there will be a executable file which is your_file.exe or your_file without extension.

This works for both 64-bit and 32-bit!