# How to convert .py to .exe (32bit)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, 32-bit, auto-py-to-exe

I created an application using `PyQt5`, and I'm willing to convert it to a 32bit executable file (`.exe`) using [`auto-py-to-exe`](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe)! I searched a lot about this and figured out that I should use a 32bit version of Python for this purpose(examples:[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48139948/18390234)],[[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22816944/18390234)],[[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4935537/18390234)],[[4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62081307/11747148)]). Since I'm comfortable with using Conda environments, I tried to make a clone from my preferred Conda environment(that contains `PyQt5` and `auto-py-to-exe`) in this way:

```
set CONDA_SUBDIR=win-32
conda create --name py32 --clone python3.10
conda activate py32
conda update --all

# Then I tried to run auto-py-to-exe
auto-py-to-exe
```

After this, I did a transformation using `auto-py-to-exe` successfully. But still, I get this error on 32bit windows when I try to execute the `.exe` file:

[image: Picture of the error]

Now I'm somewhat disappointed about how I should achieve my goal.

**Important Question:** Why did I use `set CONDA_SUBDIR=win-32`? Because I think that command helps me clone everything with 32bit format and converts my cloned Python to a 32bit version, this helps me run `auto-py-to-exe` and convert my `.py` file to a `.exe` 32bit file. But it seems I'm wrong about this since I can't run the `.exe` file in 32bit OS.

Can you please help me how I can create a 32bit version of Python in a Conda environment and then use `auto-py-to-exe` to create the 32bit `.exe` file? (I assume that `auto-py-to-exe` also uses Python for running, and the 32bit version of Python influence on `auto-py-to-exe` result.)

---

Additional details:
My OS: 64bit Windows 10
But I want to run the `.exe` file on another machine that has 32bit Windows 10

---

**Update:**
Since I didn't get an answer about Conda environments, I tried installing 32bit Python. I achieved a 32bit `.exe` file with these steps:

1. Installing `Python 3.10.1` **32bit** using [this link](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.1/python-3.10.1.exe).
2. Adding the Python path to the User variables and System variables:
   [image]
   [image]
3. Then I opened cmd and installed the required packages like `auto-py-to-exe` (also those used in `.py`) using `pip`.
4. run `auto-py-to-exe` in cmd and start converting.

The result is a 32bit `.exe` file that a 32bit OS can execute. **But** This isn't exactly what I looked for(it works, but it made me install a 32bit Python and add it to the path, which isn't what I looked for). So I write this here and **hope for someone to help me do these in a Conda environment.**

Comment: Consider using other tools that are more modern and flexible, like cx_freeze or pyinstaller. Also, *conda environments are not really intended for such usage, and you should consider more standard situations: for a standalone application there is very little use of a similar type of environment, and standard usage will actually be much more flexible (and easier to debug).

Comment: @musicamante I should mention that as stated in the [official GitHub of `auto-py-to-exe`](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe), *"Auto PY to EXE, A .py to .exe converter using a simple graphical interface and PyInstaller in Python."* thanks for your advice. Can you explain more about *"standard usage"*? I'll check `cx_freeze` as well.

Comment: Where is it written that you need a 32-bit environment?

Comment: @musicamante I read about it on a website(I don't remember the address). Do you have a better idea?

Comment: I don't see any reference of that requirement on the official github, so why don't you just try to use the default 64-bit system you probably already have?

Comment: @musicamante Try to use it for what purpose exactly? Can you please make this clear?

Comment: In the official `auto-py-to-exe` there is no reference that says that you need to use a 32-bit environment, so why don't you just use the current 64-bit one you are already using?

Comment: @musicamante, isn't this obvious from my explains in the question? Because that gives me a 64bit executable file! But I'm looking for a 32bit one, not a 64bit!

Comment: Ok, so I probably misunderstood your question, sorry for that. Now, if you **really** do need a 32-bit executable, well, that's not easy nowadays. This brings us back to the original point: if you just need a final executable, creating a full conda environment is completely pointless; you just need a basic 32-bit python environment, so, even if you may not like it, you have to stick with it. Besides: if you need a 32-bit environment, all executable-related 32-bit files will need to be installed; that is a basic requirement.

Comment: @musicamante, do you know how to create an environment with 32-bit python? I'm so okay with the "environments" like virtual environments. What bothers me is to install a new 32-bit python and add it to the default PATH.

Comment: As said, it's not that easy nowadays, as most situations will prevent that for various reasons. A possible alternative (somehow easier and less invasive) could be to install a virtual machine with an OS that still supports that architecture. I'm assuming you're using Windows, so I cannot really help you there, but I believe that there are still ways to install a not-so-old Windows version that still runs on 32-bit. What puzzles me is: why do you need a 32-bit executable? If you have a target 32-bit machine, can't you do the builds on *that* machine?

Comment: @musicamante, Thanks! No, unfortunately, I can't. I tried to run the procedure on the 32-bit machine, but it was too slow and weak for that :))) it's a kind of HP Tablet PC.

Comment: Then, a VM is probably the best choice. Consider that the 64-bit migration began lots of years ago, and there are modules and libraries that may not be available anymore. My suggestion is to take your time (*a lot of time*, be patient!), learn how to properly create a valid 32-bit Windows machine, possibly with the target OS, and then carefully read all the documentation about installing a valid environment. Note that you might need to be very careful in reading docs and tutorials: check their modification date, as they might not be valid anymore (because they're too old, or even too modern!).

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for putting time into this. I appreciate it. Indeed I'll consider your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Conda environment use venv or pipenv. you can't convert conda environment `.py` file to exe because of its dependency.While using venv use pyinstaller. install comand -
`pip install pyinstaller`
convert command -
`pyinstaller --onefile -w 'filename.py'`
When using pipenv use auto-py-to-exe. yeah  auto-py-to-exe is old, but there are no other tools.as for conda you can't do anything.

Comment: you can't do anything for conda, use venv and pipenv